# Is there any way to permanently retain specific cookies, when deleting all cookies on Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

I am wanting to be able to delete all cookies with one button click, or even a hotkey would be better, while *not* deleting certain commonly used websites' cookies. More specifically, I want to save the cookies for Facebook, Gmail, and a couple of my work websites, while quickly deleting all other cookies. Is there a way this can be done?

Currently, I have the option of either deleting *all* cookies, or going through and handpicking out individual websites to delete, and there are always far more cookies that I want to delete than save. Is there a better way?

Comment: "Handpicking individual websites..." to do what, save or delete? The way the question is phrased it appears you've already got a solution, but it's obvious you don't. Please EDIT your question to make if more clear.

Comment: In Microsoft Edge (chromium) there is the ability to set sites whose cookies are not deleted when cookies are deleted on exit (https://winaero.com/keep-cookies-for-specific-sites-when-close-microsoft-edge/) but I was unable to find a similar setting in Chrome documentation.

Comment: OH NOOOO!!! This is bad news. I may end up switching to Edge over this... It's been such a long run with Chrome.